# how to select the default value and perform event using angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi i am having dynamic  data using which im generating drop down  and below is my dropdown code

```
<select  #selHo (change)="onHoChange($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let Ho of HDropDown" [value]= "Ho.id">
        {{Ho.Name}}
      </option>
</select>
```

here i also want to perform the action based on dropdown selection so i wrote  **change** when ever the change occurs it will the below function

```
public onHoChange(event): void {  
    this.cardDataHOTable(event.target.value) // this is will generate table 
  }


cardDataHOTable(data) {
    this.serv.getCardMaster(data).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

dropdown code:

```
 this.serv.loadDropdown(1).subscribe(res => {

      console.log(res);
      this.HDropDown = res;
    });
```

i m loading this in constructor

here up to this here the issue i am facing is on `ngonit()` i am loading dropdown based on the dropdown values  a table has to be generated . On change i am able to perform the task but i unable to get the default value of dropdown and on init i unable to generate the table

Comment: from your code seems everything fine,

Comment: @PrasanthS actually the table is generating after i changing dropdown  and it has to happend even on loading the page a default option is load on that also a table has to be generated based on that value also

Comment: intialize in ngOnInit with you want as default  "this.cardDataHOTable(this.id || 12)"

Comment: @PrasanthS Check the code updated

Comment: show your full code including the ngOnInit and how you get the data for your dropdown

Comment: @brijmcq updated the dropdown code and i didnt init any thing in ngonit

Comment: your select must have [value]=variable. then you can use variable=res[0]

Comment: @Eliseo Where should i use variable=res[0]